# Use parts of default WPF controls for binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Is it possible to use the parts of default WPF controls for binding?

Specifically, I'm aiming at binding the padding size of a ListBox control to the width of the arrow part of a ComboBox control.

Using VS 2015 Live Visual Tree, I can see that the specific part I'm interested in is named 'splitBorder', which is the portion of the ComboBoxToggleButton that contains the downwards arrow symbol. [image: ComboBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Specifically, I'm aiming at binding the padding size of a ListBox control to the width of the arrow part of a ComboBox control.

No, you can't really do this since the width of the arrow and the arrow itself is hardcoded within the ControlTemplate of a ToggleButton that is part of the default ControlTemplate of the ComboBox.

You cannot bind to the arrow Path from any element outside of the control template where it is defined and the ComboBox class doesn't expose the arrow from any public property that the ListBox can bind to. So this is not possible I am afraid.